# How can I read and parse very large flat file using thread in C#?

Tags: c#

I have to read a large text file and to parse it line by line using C#. It could be done easily with `StreamReader` for small sized file but it caught out of memory exception while working with large file. How can I adapt it for large files?

Following code catches `OutOfMemoryException` :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileNameWithPath))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Do something here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line catches Exception? This code looks fine for me.

Comment: the exception seems to be from "Do something here..." - so what exactly are you doing (some code please) ?

Comment: By realizing you totally misrepresent the facts. It is NOT the stream reader causing an out of memory exception, and not the reading, it is the code "// do something here" that we do not see. Naturally unless you have many hundred megabytes in one line.

Comment: I agree that it's likely to be a problem in // Do something here..., but also note that if you're using .Net 4 or later you can use File.ReadLines() to get a string enumerator that you can use with foreach. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Answer (score 10):

That is pretty much the standard code for a lazy line reader, and shouldn't cause an `OutOfMemoryException` unless there are some ***really*** big single lines. You could also try:

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(FileNameWithPath)) {
    // Do something here...
}
```

which just makes it cleaner, but does the same thing. So there are two options:

1. one or more of the "lines" is simply huge
2. something in "Do something here" is slowly (or quickly) eating your memory

I expect the latter is more likley.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure with this but give try to this class of .net framework

[**MemoryMappedFile Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx)-A memory-mapped file maps the contents of a file to an application’s logical address space. Memory-mapped files enable programmers to work with extremely large files because memory can be managed concurrently, and they allow complete, random access to a file without the need for seeking. Memory-mapped files can also be shared across multiple processes.

Comment: while that is true, a `StreamReader` seems entirely appropriate for the situation described.

Comment: @MarcGravell - agree with you but i just read about this class few weeks ago ...but nit tried but this might helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var inputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(sourceFilePath))
{
    while (inputFile.Peek() >= 0) {
        string lineData = inputFile.ReadLine();

        // Do something with lineData
    }
}
```

Comment: That check is semantically identical to the `null` check in the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

How about specify the buffer size ?

like this.

```
using (var reader = new StreamWriter(path,false,Encoding.UTF8, 1000))
{
    .....

}
```